# Installing Windows 2012 server patches

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, patching, windows-server-2012-r2

I was recently on a support call with Microsoft and the engineer told me I should run `psconfig` after installing `SharePoint 2013` AND `windows server OS updates`.

I questioned him twice on the windows server updates and he said I should. Running `psconfig` after OS server patches, especially because of the frequency they come out, significantly raises the bar for us.

This doesn't make sense to me so I wanted to run it past people here who probably have a lot more knowledge of this subject than me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should not run the PSConfig after the windows / OS patches or updates. But now a days MSFT include the SharePoint patches in the windows updates, so if you noticed SharePoint patch install along with the windows then you need to run the PSConfig.

we block the windows updates and manually install the windows updates. We never run the config wizard after windows Upadate nor we have the issue with it.